# What is $P(a>c)$, if $P(a>b)=p_1$ and $P(b>c)=p_2$?

Tags: probability

Let's say we have three different real numbers that we know are different from each other. And we know that $P(a>b)=p_1$ and $P(b>c)=p_2$. Then What would be the value of $P(a>c)$?

I thought it maybe something like this:

$P(a>c)=P(a>c~|~a>b~\wedge~b>c)~P(a>b~\wedge~b>c)
\\+P(a>c~|~a>b~\wedge~b<c)~P(a>b~\wedge~b<c)
\\+P(a>c~|~a<b~\wedge~b>c)~P(a<b~\wedge~b>c)
\\+P(a>c~|~a<b~\wedge~b<c)~P(a<b~\wedge~b<c).$

Now we know that $P(a>c~|~a>b~\wedge~b>c)=1$ and $P(a>c~|~a<b~\wedge~b<c)=0$ so it should become something like this:

$P(a>c)=p_1 p_2
\\+P(a>c~|~a>b~\wedge~b<c)~p_1(1-p_2)
\\+P(a>c~|~a<b~\wedge~b>c)~(1-p_1)p_2.$

So is the above expressions correct? And if so, how can I determine $P(a>c~|~a>b~\wedge~b<c)$ and $P(a>c~|~a<b~\wedge~b>c)$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You haven't given any other information about the real numbers(which are basically random variables). If the random variables are independent and identically distributed the the answer would be $\frac12$

Comment: If $a>c$, why must $b$ be between them?  That $b$ is between $a$ and $c$ is, essentially, what your first equation implies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the random variables $X=a-b$ and $Y=b-c$. You are asking what is known about $\mathbb P(X+Y>0)$ if the probabilities $\mathbb P(X>0)$ and $\mathbb P(Y>0)$ are given.

In general, $\mathbb P(X+Y>0)$ is not determined by $\mathbb P(X>0)$ and $\mathbb P(Y>0)$. However, one can get bounds. Notice that $$\min(X,Y)\leq \frac{X+Y}{2}\leq \max(X,Y),$$
from which it follows that
$$
\mathbb P(\min(X,Y)>0)\leq \mathbb P(X+Y>0)\leq \mathbb P(\max(X,Y)>0).
$$
If we further assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then we can calculate these bounds explicitly as follows.
$$
\mathbb P(\min(X,Y)>0)=\mathbb P(X>0)\cdot \mathbb P(Y>0),
$$
and
$$
\mathbb P(\max(X,Y)>0)=\mathbb P(X>0)+ \mathbb P(Y>0) - \mathbb P(X>0)\cdot \mathbb P(Y>0).
$$

This translates into the following bound in your notation:
$$
p_1p_2\leq \mathbb P(a>c)\leq p_1+p_2-p_1p_2.
$$

The actual value of $\mathbb P(a>c)$ can range anywhere between these two extremes.